# Whatsapp web js not working with electronjs

Tags: electron, whatsapp, electron-builder

I make a project in electronJS with whatsapp-web.js. When i debug with npm start it works properly.
but when I build with electron and install the (.exe) file the project don't works. It seems the Puppeteer not running. How can I solve the problem?
NB: I am using electron-builder for build the application for Windows.

```js
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testapp",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.testapp.test",
    "productName": "testapp",
    "target": "NSIS",
    "nsis" : {
      "oneClick" : true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory" : false
    }
  },
  "author": "Udayan Basak",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^15.3.1",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.15.2"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json data.
[Again: full project working fine in development mode. It causes error in production lavel.]

```js
const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, ipcRenderer } = require('electron') 
const client = new Client();
client.on('qr', (qr) => {
    win.webContents.send("qrcode", qr)
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    win.webContents.send("ready", "ready")
})
```

Comment: Without showing us at least some of the relevant information, it's impossible to help you -- it could be anything, really. Please [edit] your question and include the relevant dependency entries in your `package.json` and at least the initialisation code of the WhatsApp library. Thanks!

Comment: Hello @AlexanderLeithner , I added the full package.json file and the some parts of main.js file. All works fine in develpoment mood. but it not works wheren I build and install the exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your webpack config?
Maybe adding the following can help:

```
optimization: { minimize: false }
```